# Apache2 Config Public IP

Tags: apache, config, alias, vhosts

I've got Apache installed via XAMPP on my Windows machine, I've forwarded port 80 so that it's accessible from outside the local network, and everything is good.

However, I'm working with laravel and am trying to make it so that each of my sites are accessible via a different path.

For example, site 1's public directory would be C:\xampp\htdocs\site1\public which I would like to be able to access from `http://<public_ip>/site1` or `http://<public_ip>/~site1`. Similarly, if I created another project, I'd like to be able to access it in the same way using an alias on my public IP address.

Would I use vhosts for this? Alias'? Or how would I accomplish it?
I'm new to configuring apache, I've tried reading the docs but they have only managed to confuse me even further.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to modify your httpd.vhosts.conf file in the "config/extra" folder. Also you will have to modify the hosts file. I'm not sure where that is in Windows.

Here is something that might help.
http://sawmac.com/xampp/virtualhosts/

Comment: Why would I have to edit my hosts file? I'm wanting to access the site via IP, not some custom hostname... This question is, more-or-less, pertaining to how to setup multiple sites and making http://host/path point to http://host/path/public

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I'm not sure how that works.

Is this more what you are looking for?http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/ip-based.html